# Convergence, Divergence of $\int_1^∞ e^{ax} x^b dx. $

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Let $a>0, \  b \in \mathbb R$.

Consider the convergence, divergence of the integral
$$\int_1^∞ e^{ax} x^b dx. $$

I think this diverges to $\infty.$

Here is my proof.

Since $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{ax} x^b = \infty,$ there is $\delta >1$ s.t. $x \geqq \delta \Rightarrow e^{ax} x^b \geqq 1.$

\begin{align}
\int_1^∞ e^{ax} x^b dx 
&=\int_1^\delta e^{ax} x^b dx+\int_\delta^\infty e^{ax} x^b dx \\
&\geqq \int_1^\delta e^{ax} x^b dx +\int_\delta^\infty 1 \ dx \\
&=\infty \ \left(\because \int_\delta^\infty 1 \ dx = \infty.\right)
\end{align}

Thus $\int_1^∞ e^{ax} x^b dx=\infty.$

Is this consequence correct ? Is there some deficiency in my proof ?

Comment: No, your proof is fine.

Comment: I do not like to use infinity and divergent integrals usually when I write a proof, but here since everything is positive it can be considered as rigorous.